# How to validate different properties from an object?

Tags: java, validation

I'm looking for a good way or a framework that helps me validating the properties of an object. I get the object from another library, thus cannot change anything on the object itself.

I know these annotations from Hibernate like @NotNull, @Size etc. But as I cannot change the objects source code, I cannot use this.

```
class Person {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String gender;
    int age;
}
```

Now I'd like to apply different validators and return a custom error message for each property. I'd like to validate that:

- each field is not empty, not null
- gender is either male or female
- age is > 0
- firstname is max 25 chars
- lastname is max 25 chars

How would I apply such validation? Write endless if clauses for each validation and return the error message there in?

```
if (age < 0) {
    throw CustomError("Age must be > 0");
}
if (gender != GENDER.MALE || gender != GENDER.FEMALE) {
    throw CustomError("Gender must be either male or female");
}
//etc
```

Or could I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of validation frameworks out there which could be useful - I created [this one](https://kenai.com/projects/simplevalidation) a number of years ago which is used inside [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) and in some other public projects.

There is also Java EE 6's [Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) for validating whole objects.